# How do I detect change to ngModel on a select tag (Angular 2)?

Tags: javascript, angular

I am attempting to detect a change on `ngModel` in a `<select>` tag. In Angular 1.x, we might solve this with a `$watch` on `ngModel`, or by using `ngChange`, but I've yet to understand how to detect a change to `ngModel` in Angular 2.

**Full Example**: http://plnkr.co/edit/9c9oKH1tjDDb67zdKmr9?p=info

```
import {Component, View, Input, } from 'angular2/core';
import {FORM_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/common';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-dropdown'
})
@View({
    directives: [FORM_DIRECTIVES],
    template: `
        <select [ngModel]="selection" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event, selection)" >
            <option *ngFor="#option of options">{{option}}</option>
        </select>
        {{selection}}
    `
})
export class MyDropdown {
    @Input() options;

    selection = 'Dog';

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log('These were the options passed in: ' + this.options);
  }

  onChange(event) {
    if (this.selection === event) return;
    this.selection = event;
    console.log(this.selection);
  }

}
```

As we can see, if we select a different value from the dropdown, our `ngModel` changes, and the interpolated expression in the view reflects this.

How do I get notified of this change in my class/controller?

Comment: you might want to keep some of the extra comments in check; you don't want this question to be flagged as a rant in disguise.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask.

Answer (score 318, accepted):

**Update**:

Separate the event and property bindings:

```
<select [ngModel]="selectedItem" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)">
```

```
onChange(newValue) {
    console.log(newValue);
    this.selectedItem = newValue;  // don't forget to update the model here
    // ... do other stuff here ...
}
```

You could also use

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedItem" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)">
```

and then you wouldn't have to update the model in the event handler, but I believe this causes two events to fire, so it is probably less efficient.

---

Old answer, before they fixed a bug in beta.1:

Create a local template variable and attach a `(change)` event:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedItem" #item (change)="onChange(item.value)">
```

<kbd>[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/1gCJ9IcDiwM1ifvsQByi?p=preview)</kbd>

See also [How can I get new selection in "select" in Angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33700266/how-can-i-get-new-selection-in-select-in-angular-2)

Comment: So what's the point of `ngModel` if I'm just binding a new variable called `item`? Isn't the point of wrapping `ngModel` in parenthesis to acquire event listeners, so why are we introducing a new variable?

Comment: @lux, yeah good question.  `selectedItem` is our bound data, which NgModel updates automatically for us, but... it doesn't notify us of changes, which often is good enough (views and such will update), but obviously this is not good enough for your use case.  In the other SO question I referenced, I describe how I tried to use `(ngModelChange)` to get notified of changes, but it gets called twice for each change.  I don't know if that is a bug or not.  Anyway, adding a `(change)` event binding seems to solve the issue.

Comment: Also, I updated the plunker which shows that `selectedItem` is not updated when `onChange()` fires, hence it seems we need that local template variable.

Comment: @lux the `#` or `#item` in our case is a **local** reference. Hence why we're able to do `item.change` there.

Comment: @lux, I already described the way to hook in: bind to the `ngModelChange` custom event.  The problem is, with `<select>`, this event fires twice for every change.

Comment: @lux, I think you should add your solution as another answer.

Comment: @lux If you decouples the event binding from the property assignment, what is the job of `[ngModel]="selection"`? What I don't understand is that once you make them apart like `[ngModel]="someProperty"` and `(ngModelChange)="handler"`, `ngModelChange` event still fires with the value of what user chose but `someProperty` doesn't change unless you do it yourself as @Mark Rajcok mentioned earlier.

Answer (score 20):

I have stumbled across this question and I will submit my answer that I used and worked pretty well. I had a search box that filtered and array of objects and on my search box I used the `(ngModelChange)="onChange($event)"`

in my `.html`

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="searchText" (ngModelChange)="reSearch(newValue)" placeholder="Search">
```

then in my `component.ts`

```
reSearch(newValue: string) {
    //this.searchText would equal the new value
    //handle my filtering with the new value
}
```

Comment: Just FYI, when binding to `ngModelChange`, `$event` is not a DOM [Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event).  Rather it is the current value of the form element, which is a string for an input element.

Comment: @MarkRajcok can you please point me to documentation for this, so i can share with the rest of my dev team?

Comment: @NeilS, the closest is https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#ngModel