# Angular 7: How to call a function when the value of a <select> element changes?

Tags: angular, events, angular7

I have an HTML  element in a component template, and need to trigger a function in my typescript file for the component when the selected option changes.

What I have tried so far:

1. Putting a (click) on the select. This did not work because it triggers when the select is clicked, before an option is selected.
2. Putting a (click) on the  of the select element. For some reason, this did not work.

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
        <select name="sort-by" 
                id="sort-by" 
                class="form-control"
                (<someEvent>)="myFunc()">
          <option value="lotNumber" >Lot Number  </option>
          <option value="firstName" >First Name  </option>
          <option value="lastName"  >Last Name   </option>
        </select>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect change to ngModel on a select tag (Angular 2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34405301/detect-change-to-ngmodel-on-a-select-tag-angular-2)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using the `(change)` event. This will trigger `myFunc()` whenever the selected option changes.

```
<select name="sort-by" id="sort-by" class="form-control" (change)="myFunc()">
     <option value="lotNumber" >Lot Number  </option>
     <option value="firstName" >First Name  </option>
     <option value="lastName"  >Last Name   </option>
</select>
```