# ngModel and change method on input does not work

Tags: angular, angular-ngmodel

I have the following HTML template

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="mobile" (change)="mobileChanged()">
```

Here is my .ts

```
mobileChanged = () => {
    console.log(this.mobile);
};
```

Is it wrong to have `ngModel` and `change` in the same element? In my case `mobileChanged` is not being called while I type in the input. How ever, when I check the value of `mobile`, it is updated correctly.

This is Angular 7.

Comment: is your input in a formgroup ?

Comment: You should be using ngModelChange instead of change event https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34405301/detect-change-to-ngmodel-on-a-select-tag-angular-2

Comment: @Nicolas yes, it is

Comment: You might have to add the `[ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"` option.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using `change` will trigger the `mobileChanged()` when you lose the focus of the input field (ex: Click outside the field). If you want to trigger `mobileChanged()` while typing, use `(ngModelChange)="mobileChanged($event)"` instead.

Comment: yes, that did it. and keypress like events also works

Answer (score 0):

I sugest to read this tutorial : 
https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/10/13/two-way-data-binding-in-angular-2.html
in order to understand well the two-way Data Binding and to master the use of ngModel.

As it's explained using `ngModel` bind an expression to the element’s `input` event, so it's similar to :

```
<input [value]="mobile" (input)="mobile = $event.target.value">
```

you could manage the update of the value and your log in the same method called.