# Get selected option value on change event in Angular

Tags: angular, html-select, angular-reactive-forms, onchange

I'm using Angular's reactive form in order to submit form data. I want to be able to access selected option value from one of my inputs similar to how I currently do when I submit the form.

```
(ngSubmit)="onSubmit(searchForm.value)"
```

Notice the filters array:

[image]

However when I make a selection change I cannot get the same result, as `event.target.value` logs `3: Object`

HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-2" *ngFor="let filter of this.filters; index as i" formArrayName="filters" >
          <div class="form-group">
            <select [formControlName]="i" (change)="onSelectChange($event.target.value)" size="5" class="form-control" multiple>
              <option [ngValue]="null" value="-1" disabled class="first-option-item">{{ filter.name }}</option>
              <option
                *ngFor="let filterValue of this.filterValues[i].items"
                [ngValue]="{
                  filterHeader: { id: filter.id, value: filter.name },
                  filterSelections: { id: filterValue.id, value: filterValue.name }
                }">
                {{filterValue.name}}
              </option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you create stackblitz?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xm5vhf

Answer (score 3):

I managed to get the selected option value adding (ngModelChange) to select element and [ngValue] for the options. It wasn't necessary to add [(ngModel)] too.

```html
<select [formControlName]="i" (ngModelChange)="onSelectChange($event)" size="5" class="form-control" multiple>
    <option [ngValue]="null" value="-1" disabled class="first-option-item">{{ filter.name }}</option>
    <option *ngFor="let filterValue of this.filterValues[i].items" [ngValue]="filterValue">
        {{filterValue.name}}
    </option>
</select>
```

Comment: If you only use the `$event` to get the selected value, I suggest to bind the value directly to `[(ngModel)]`, this makes your code more readable.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you store the selected value in an extra variable. And use the `[(value)]` binding within your template, but currently I am not sure if this works for the native select. I use this with my [anuglar-material components](https://material.angular.io/components/select/examples).

```html
<select [formControlName]="i" (change)="onSelectChange($event.target.value)" size="5" class="form-control" multiple>
    <option [ngValue]="null" value="-1" disabled class="first-option-item">{{ filter.name }}</option>
    <option
        *ngFor="let filterValue of this.filterValues[i].items"
        [ngValue]="{
            filterHeader: { id: filter.id, value: filter.name },
            filterSelections: { id: filterValue.id, value: filterValue.name }
        }">
      {{filterValue.name}}
    </option>
</select>
```

Another solution is to use `[(ngModel)]`  with `(ngModelChange)="yourfunction"`, this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34405301/detect-change-to-ngmodel-on-a-select-tag-angular-2) might be helpful.

```html
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedItem" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)">
```