# Call a method when the value is changed using Angular 2

Tags: ionic-framework, angular

How can i call a method when the value is changed using Angular 2?

```
 <select [(ngModel)]="searchMonster">
     <option>36</option>
     <option>37</option>
 </select>
```

I tried to use ng-change but had no success.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get new selection in "select" in Angular 2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33700266/how-can-i-get-new-selection-in-select-in-angular-2)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Basically upto my observations `[(ngModel)]` is called when we have to use two way data Binding in angular. so view and controller/method is called via binding. we can use [(ngModel)] as [ngModel] and (ngModelChange) for change detection but in This case `onChange()` gets called twice for each select list change that way according to this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33716321/5043867) but as you want to call a method on change you can use this way here:-

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedDevice" #device (change)="onChange(device.value)">
    <option *ngFor="#i of devices">{{i}}</option>
</select>

onChange(deviceValue) {
    console.log(deviceValue);
}
```

i found best answer to this question is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33716321/5043867)

Answer (score 9):

Use `ngModelChange`.  check the [template syntax docs.](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#ngModel)

try this

```
<select
  [ngModel]="searchMonster"
  (ngModelChange)="yourMethod($event)">
     <option>36</option>
     <option>37</option>
</select>
```

an alternative worked with me for `<input>` tag, try this for `<select>`

```
<select #option
  [ngModel]="searchMonster"
  (ngModelChange)="yourMethod(option.value)">
     <option>36</option>
     <option>37</option>
</select>
```