# How to get the value in a select change event in angular2

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to navigate useing a dynamically generated select drop down.
It doesn't appear I can do that directly, so I'd simply like to make a function call when the select changes.

To do that, I have this:

---In the template---

```
<select (change)="navSelected($event)">
    <option *ngFor="let button of navButtons;"
    value="button.route" >{{button.label}}</option>
</select>
```

suffice it to say that 'navButtons' is an array of objects that have a 'label' field.

---In the class---

```
navSelected(navName) {
    console.log(navName + " Clicked!");
}
```

This actually works fine.

I got to this point from the great help of Mark Rajcok and his answer in this older question:
[How can I get new selection in "select" in Angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33700266/how-can-i-get-new-selection-in-select-in-angular-2)

That said, I'd like to be able to pass the selected value in the navSelected() function call.  I'm unsure how to do that.

I have tried adding `[ngValue]="button"` on a wild guess from other searches to the option tag and then referencing the `button` variable in the `(change)` event handler (so: `(change)="navSelected(button.label)"` and other combos, to no avail.   I've seen a lot of references to ngModel but they seem old and I'm not entirely sure they apply anymore (and I couldn't get them to work anyway in RC4).

I could probably pull some jquery or whatever out to find the select and get it's value, but that seems very rinky-dink compared to simply being able to call the function correctly.

Comment: you need to get button.route or button.label?

Comment: either one.  Really, anything from the button object to denote which item was selected.  Even the index of the ngFor would be fine.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The value you are looking for is on the `$event.target` and you can get it with `$event.target.value`, see my example below.

```
navSelected($event) {
    console.log($event.target.value + " Clicked!");
}
```

If you are looking to get the selected text of the option you can do this

```
navSelected($event) {
    let selectElement = $event.target;
    var optionIndex = selectElement.selectedIndex;
    var optionText = selectElement.options[optionIndex];
    console.log(optionText + " Clicked!");
}
```

Comment: After changing the binding of button.route to `{{button.route}}` that works. What if I simply wanted to get the object passed in (button), rather than a value string?

Comment: if you needed a dynamic value attribute you would have to bind this way `[value]="button.route"`.

Comment: So I change the binding to `[value]="button"`.  (again, trying to get the object, itself).  in my navSelected(navName) function I see the toString() results of the button object outputted to the console.  yay.   However, if I try to access the object like an object and output it's parameters: `console.log(navName.route)` I get undefined.

Comment: @lowcrawler now that is like a stringified version of the object you will have to use `JSON.parse(value).route`. it makes things more complex than they need to be. if you can just stick to passing the route or label that you need

Comment: Cool, thanks.  Your first comments solved the direct problem I was having, and then I was just trying to learn more. Thanks for indulging me.

Answer (score 1):

As a shortcut for @eltonkamami 's answer, you can pass your object like this:

```
<select (change)="navSelected(navButtons[$event.target.selectedIndex])">
    <option *ngFor="let button of navButtons;">{{button.label}}</option>
</select>
```

And capture it like this:

```
navSelected(button: [type of navButtons]){
    console.log(button);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of $event. Try using the below typecast function.

> $any($event.target).value

Which will stop the type checking in the template.