# Angular 2 - TypeScript: how to hold objects with <Select> control

Tags: typescript, angular

I am coming from a desktop application background, probably this could be a very basic question for web developers. I am using Angular 2 with TypeScript for a demo application. Following is my code -

```
    <select required [(ngModel)]="model.SelectedSchool">
       <option *ngFor="let school of schools" [value]="school">
         {{school.Name}}
       </option>
    </select>
```

Here "schools" is an array of School object, where School further contains array of other objects like Class[], Teacher[] and some other properties of string and int type.

I need when user select any School in the above code, School object should be assigned to SelectedSchool property in my associated Component for this form.

It works when I assign any string/number type like "SelectedSchoolId" or "SelectedSchoolName" to associated properties of component, but shows target property - "SelectedSchool" as undefined when I want the same with any object.

Am I doing something wrong in the above code, or is it not possible to passback any object type back to component class.

Thanks

Comment: Seems like [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33700266/how-can-i-get-new-selection-in-select-in-angular-2) has what you need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ngValue` instead of `value`

```
<select required [(ngModel)]="model.SelectedSchool">
   <option *ngFor="let school of schools" [ngValue]="school">
     {{school.Name}}
   </option>
</select>
```

As far as I remember `value` will work with objects as well with the next update (RC.r) not sure though if I don't mix something up here.

Comment: Thanks Gunter for the super quick response. It worked. 
Btw do you advice to transmission of complete objects from web-page to components, or it should be kept light?

Comment: Glad to hear. Thanks for the feedback :)