# How to get selected option from select and assign it to select ngModel

Tags: select, angular, angular2-forms, angular2-ngmodel

I have the following `select` menu:

```
<div class="medium-3 columns">
    <label>First Menu
        <select name="first-menu">
            <option *ngFor="let i of items" [value]="i.name">{{i.name}}</option>
        </select>
    </label>
</div>
```

I would assing a model to the select menu so i edited the code in the following way (i see it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33700266/how-can-i-get-new-selection-in-select-in-angular-2)):

```
<div class="medium-3 columns">
    <label>First menu
        <select [ngModel]="myForm.firstMenu" (ngModelChange)="onSelected($event)" name="first-menu">
            <option *ngFor="let i of items" [value]="i.name">{{i.name}}</option>
        </select>
    </label>
</div>
```

On `ngModelChange` it triggers the following method in the component:

```
onSelectedFirstMenu(e: any): void {
    myForm.firstMenu = e;
}
```

Since i have to add several menu, i would make code reuse so i do not want to create multiple methods like `onSelectedSecondMenu`, `onSelectedThirdMenu` and so on for every html menu.
So i just want to use a different `ngModel` for every menu (`myForm.secondMenu`, `myForm.thirdMenu` and so on...) to get the selected option.
Is it possible in Angular2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved and there are 2 ways to get the same behaviour:

First way (preferred):

```
<div class="medium-3 columns">
    <label>First Menu
        <select [(ngModel)]="myForm.firstMenu" name="first-menu">
            <option *ngFor="let i of items" [value]="i.name">{{i.name}}</option>
        </select>
    </label>
</div>
```

Second way:

```
<div class="medium-3 columns">
    <label>First Menu
        <select [ngModel]="myForm.firstMenu" (ngModelChange)="myForm.firstMenu = $event" name="first-menu">
            <option *ngFor="let i of items" [value]="i.name">{{i.name}}</option>
        </select>
    </label>
</div>
```

More info [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html#!#ngModel)

Answer (score 1):

If i understand your question correctly, every single menu has a different purpose, therefore, trying to somehow combine the invoked method for all of those menus is incorrect.

Having a method for each of those `<select>`s is the right approach, each one of them should have its' own logic

Please let me know if i misunderstood

Use `[(MyForm.firstMenu)]` to bind the select to your `firstMenu` property

Comment: I just want that when users choose `A` option, the value `A` is assigned to `myForm.firstMenu`. If users choose `B` option from the second menu, the value `B` is assigned to `myForm.secondMenu` model. And so on for next menus...

Comment: @smartmouse please do mark the answer as accepted if you found it helpful, for the future lookers to come :)

Comment: Done, thank you for the reminder ;)
I see now that someone downvote my answer :(

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do depending on your concrete requirements:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="myForm.firstMenu"
```

```
constructor() {
  this.myForm.firstMenu = items[0];
}
```