# Getting values of input field and dropdown in angular 2

Tags: angular

I am trying to get the values of an input field and a dropdown in a function . But i get the error can not read the property of null.

```js
languageSelected(name: ElementRef, languageSelect: ElementRef) {
    alert(languageSelect.nativeElement.value);
}
```

The view is below.

```html
<div class="form-group row">
   <label class="col-md-3 form-control-label" for="name">{{'movieCategory.name'|translate}}</label>
   <div class="col-md-5">
      <input #categoryNameInput [disabled]="pageStatus==4" ngModel="{{movieCategory.name}}"  name="name" id="name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="{{'movieCategory.placeHolder.name'|translate}}">
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-3">
      <select #languageSelection class="form-control">
         <option value="tr">Türkçe</option>
         <option value="en">İngilizce</option>
         <option value="de">Almanca</option>
      </select>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-1">
      <i (click)="languageSelected(categoryNameInput,languageSelection)" class="fa fa-plus fa-2x" style="margin-top:5px;margin-left:-15px;color:green"  aria-hidden="true"></i>
   </div>
</div>
```

Btw when i try alert(languageSelect)  instead , it alerts [object HTMLSelectElement] which is okay i think.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `.value` to the console.log value as by deafult it passes in the whole html markup where as you need the value.

```
languageSelected(categoryNameInput,languageSelection){
    console.log(categoryNameInput.value);
    console.log(languageSelection.value);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the quick answer. What if i also want to access to name of the selection. Lets say "İngilizce" when "en" is selected ?

Comment: @rematnarab its better you use angular forms for the same [Reactive forms](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/reactive) and [template driven](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/template) . Also you can check this [ans](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39409050/2708210)