# angular 2 (change) event not firing

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following function in my component:

```
onProductSelect(e){
        var attrs = document.getElementById('firstAttr');        
        return this.groupComponentSvs.getProduct(e.target.value)
                      .subscribe(
                            selectProduct=>{                                
                                this.selectProduct=selectProduct; 
                                var select = "<select class='form-control' id='"+ selectProduct.attribute +"' (change)='selectNextAttr($event)' name='selectProd'>";
                                console.log(select);
                                    select+= '<option value="0">Select</option>';
                                for (var i=0; i<selectProduct.values.length; i++)  {
                                    select+= '<option value='+ selectProduct.values[i]+ '>'+ selectProduct.values[i] +'</option>';
                                }  
                                select+='</select>' ;                                
                                attrs.innerHTML = '<div id=attr_'+ selectProduct.attribute +'>'+ select +'</div>';                              
                                error=>this.errorMessage = <any>error
                            }                            
                )                 

    }

selectNextAttr(attr, val){
 console.log("this is a test");
}
```

I am able to insert the select menu in my html page but the change event is not being triggered with I select an item. Can someone let me know why this is happening?

Thanks

Comment: Please share your HTML code

Comment: Yes sure there is an issue with `(change)` event in Angular 2. It works same as `(blur)` if you notice carefully.. Yes you can use `(ngModelChange)` which triggers as soon as there is some change in input from user

Answer (score 9):

HTML added using `[innerHTML]="..."` is **not** processed in any way by Angular and bindings, components, directives are not created for such HTML.
The only thing Angular does with such HTML is sanitization for security purposes.

Therefore, you can't use `[ngModel]="..."` or `(ngModelChange)="..."`

One way to deal with such requirements is to dynamically create components at runtime and use the created HTML as a template for such a component.
See [Equivalent of $compile in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34784778/equivalent-of-compile-in-angular-2/37044960#37044960) on how this can be done.

Answer (score 5):

Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33716321/2114024

Try:

```
<select [ngModel]='selectedProduct' 
        class='form-control' 
        [id]='"+ selectProduct.attribute +"' 
        (ngModelChange)='selectNextAttr($event)' name='selectProd'>
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me, still does not seem to work. If I do the following it works but I need to add this dynamically using ts:

Comment: HTML Code: <select class="form-control" id="{{selectProduct.attribute}}" (change)="selectNextAttr(selectProduct.attribute,selectProduct.product_id)" name="selectProd">
                      <option value="0">Select</option>
                      <option *ngFor = "let prod of selectProduct.values" value="{{prod}}">{{prod}}</option>                    
                </select>

Comment: TS:onProductSelect(e){
        //var attrs = document.getElementById('firstAttr');        
        return this.groupComponentSvs.getProduct(e.target.value)
                      .subscribe(
                            selectProduct=>{                                
                                this.selectProduct=selectProduct;                                                     
                                error=>this.errorMessage = <any>error
                            }                            
                )                 
                
    }

Answer (score 1):

You should use **`ngModelChange`** instead of **`change`**

```
 "<select class='form-control' id='"+ selectProduct.attribute +"' (ngModelChange)='selectNextAttr($event)' name='selectProd'>"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method:

```
selectNextAttr(attr, val) {
  console.log("this is a test");
}
```

This is expecting 2 parameters, whereas in the usage you have passed only one:

```
var select = "<select class='form-control' id='"+ selectProduct.attribute +"' (change)='selectNextAttr($event)' name='selectProd'>";
```

If you want to get only the value of the selected item, change method signature as below.

```
selectNextAttr(event) {
  // this will give the selected item value.
  console.log("this is a test", event.target.value);
}
```