# How to make cascading dropdown in a Angular Reactive Formarray work without messing the dropdown value

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, cascadingdropdown, formarray

I have a form in angular 4 that containing First Name + Last Name and a formarray containing 2 dropdown(select) working as cascading dropdown and a delete button.
The rest of the form also contains a send button and a add option button. I added a screenshot down here for you to understand better. The forms add , remove button and send button works there is 1 problem the cascading dropdown works only when there is 1 cascading dropdown ,when I add an extra cascading select the value from previous groups of cascading select  second select get messed up. I added pics down here for a better explantion

[image]

As you can see on the 2nd and the 3rd picture the cascadingdropdown is working
When I change select in Criteria I fet the right options to select in the 2nd dropdown
[image]

[image]

[image]

On the 4th picture 5th Ppicture and 6th Picture you can see the add options button works but when I select a Criteria in Option 2 first dropdown it messed up with Option 1 2nd Dropwown also now it contains the dropdown choices from the 2nd Option

[image]

[image]

Here is my html code

```html
<form [formGroup] = "profileForm">

  <h1>Profile Form</h1>

 <div>
  <label for = "first-name-input">First Name</label>
  <input type="text" id="first-name-input" formControlName ="firstNameInput">
</div>
 <div>
    <label for = "last-name-input">Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="last-name-input" formControlName ="lastNameInput">
  </div>

  <div formArrayName="optionGroups">

    <div *ngFor="let optionGroup of profileForm.controls['optionGroups'].controls;  let i=index "[formGroup]="optionGroup">


      <h4>Option {{ i + 1 }} </h4>




     <div>
      <label for = "select-input">Criteria</label>
      <select id="select-input" (change)="onSelectSelect($event.target.value, i)"  formControlName ="selectInput">

          <option value="0" disabled selected>Select a Criteria</option>
          <option *ngFor="let select of selects"  [value]= "select.name">{{select.id}}</option>


        </select>

        <label for = "where-input">Option</label>
        <select id="where-input" formControlName ="whereInput">
  
            <option value="0" disabled selected>Select a Option</option>
            <option *ngFor="let where of wheres" value= {{where.name}}>{{where.id}}</option>


          </select>

          <button type ="button" (click)="removeOptionGroup(i)">X</button>

         


     </div>

    </div>

   </div>
   <button type ="button" (click)="addOptionGroup()">Add Options</button>
   <div>

    <button type ="button" (click)="saveProfileForm()">Send </button>

   

   </div>

</form>
```

And here is my component file

```
export class PowComponent {

 selects: Select[];
 wheres: Where[];


 public profileForm : FormGroup;

 public addOptionGroup(){

 const fa = this.profileForm.controls["optionGroups"] as FormArray;

  fa.push(this.newOptionGroup());

  }

  public removeOptionGroup(index: number){

   const fa = this.profileForm.controls["optionGroups"] as FormArray;

    fa.removeAt(index);

   }


   public saveProfileForm(){

    console.log(this.profileForm.value);
   }



   constructor(public router: Router,  public dropdownqueryservice:    DropDownQueryService , private fb : FormBuilder) {
    this.profileForm = this.fb.group({

        firstNameInput : [ "" ],
        lastNameInput : [ "" ],
        optionGroups : this.fb.array([
            this.fb.group({

              selectInput : [ "" ],
              whereInput : [ "" ],

          }),
       ]),
    });

    this.selects = this.dropdownqueryservice.getSelect();
    this.wheres=[];

}

onSelectSelect(selectid, i) {
    this.wheres = this.dropdownqueryservice.getWhere().filter((item)=> item.selectid == selectid);

  }


 private newOptionGroup() {
  return new FormGroup({

      selectInput: new FormControl(""),
      whereInput: new FormControl(""),

  });
   }

  }
```

Comment: try using ngValue instead of value, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33700266/how-can-i-get-new-selection-in-select-in-angular-2/37313787#37313787

Comment: Im trying with ngValue but was getting more errors .

Comment: You are facing this issue because you have only one `selects` parameter and two different selects values. You have to handle multiple selects arrays with possible select values for each multiple choices input.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I mentionned previously on the comment, the issue is comming from the unique `selects` array for multiple select forms.

You will have to create an array of arrays of `Select`, that contains an array of possible criteria for each select value.

[Here is a stackblitz solution suggestion](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-49722349), I did some modification to keep it simple and to make it work. Feel free to fork and edit if you want to get more explicit about your concern.

Comment: hi I am very busy I have seen your code but since my code  has an array it I may have to figure out how to do that ,since the bounty is expiring I am giving to you. later today or tomorrow I will fork your code and post it here I am half way through it. thx

Comment: I tried your code but I think since I am using an array of objects its different here is my code   https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-49722349-6pvgkh

Comment: Here is a fixed version of your stackblitz with the suggested solution : https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-49722349-2

Comment: Thanks for the sample solution! One issue that I have with it is that when you change the first drop down - the second drop down keep the old value, which is no longer valid. What is the best way to clear the second drop box also? In my case - I use cascading drop downs which progressively filter down. So - if old value is still valid - keep it, if it isn't - clear it.

Comment: @NickGoloborodko That's one interesting remark, didn't notice. I don't know yet how it could be handled properly, could you please create a new question for this issue ?

Comment: @ibenjelloun, Hi pretty new on Angular and I am working around your solution. Which is fantastic but I am wondering there is any way to add a file upload option. Say when the user selects 'Location' from the drop-down menu, it will show file upload rather than another dropdown menu! Also, I would like to show the file content in output!