# how can I call a function and pass parameter when value in select tags changes? Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript

how can I call a function and pass parameter when value in select tags changes? 
I want to call a function whenever the value of my select tag changes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get new selection in "select" in Angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33700266/how-can-i-get-new-selection-in-select-in-angular-2)

Answer (score 0):

```
<select (change)="onChange()">
```

Answer (score 0):

In Component.html

```
<select (change)="onChangeCall($event.target.value)"
```

In Component.ts

```
onChangeCall(value) {
    console.log('selected value',value)
}
```