# Angular Select with ngFor changing first select affects second select

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to use `*ngFor` to build a bundle of multiple `<select>` (3x of them) and I found this other [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33700266/how-can-i-get-new-selection-in-select-in-angular-2) to get me going. However, the problem I have now is that they are not independent, if I change the first select, it also reflects the change on the second select (but not the third one??). One thing worth to know is that all Select have the same list, which is why the first one affects second one, but I really want them independent.

Oh I'm currently using Angular 5, so it's not the latest.

Here's the code I have to loop through the 3 Select with `*ngFor`

```
<div class="col-sm-3" *ngFor="let groupField of selectedGroupingFields; let i = index;">
<select class="form-control col-sm-6" name="groupField{{i}}" [(ngModel)]="selectedGroupingFields[i]" (ngModelChange)="groupByFieldName($event, i)">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option [ngValue]="field.id" *ngFor="let field of columnDefinitions">{{field.name}}</option>
</select>
```

With the collection being structure like this

```
selectedGroupingFields: string[] = ['', '', ''];    
columnDefinitions = [
  { id: 'title', name: 'Title'}, 
  { id: 'duration', name: 'Duration'},
  { id: 'percentComplete', name: '% Complete'},
  { id: 'start', name: 'Start'},
  { id: 'Finish', name: 'Finish'},
  { id: 'cost', name: 'Cost'},
  { id: 'effortDriven', name: 'Effort-Driven'}
];
```

To demo the problem, I made this little function that is triggered by a button click

```
changeFirstGroupBy() {
  this.selectedGroupingFields[0] = 'title';
}
```

When I click my button and execute that function, it changes the first 2 Select... why?

So I did more tests and decided to create each Select separately by recopying them 1 by 1 and just remove the `*ngFor` on the `<div>` like this

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <select class="form-control col-sm-6" name="groupField1" [(ngModel)]="selectedGroupingFields[0]" (ngModelChange)="groupByFieldName($event, i)">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option [ngValue]="field.id" *ngFor="let field of columnDefinitions">{{field.name}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <select class="form-control col-sm-6" name="groupField2" [(ngModel)]="selectedGroupingFields[1]" (ngModelChange)="groupByFieldName($event, i)">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option [ngValue]="field.id" *ngFor="let field of columnDefinitions">{{field.name}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <select class="form-control col-sm-6" name="groupField3" [(ngModel)]="selectedGroupingFields[2]" (ngModelChange)="groupByFieldName($event, i)">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option [ngValue]="field.id" *ngFor="let field of columnDefinitions">{{field.name}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

and that works! but why? That is supposed to be the exact same code as the `*ngFor`. Also if I change the last select (see in demo), it affects the second select too, that is so strange but it's really working correctly when I create all 3 Select manually.

Here's an animated GIF of the problem

[image]

**EDIT**

Forgot to mention, I also tried to change 2 way binding to 1 way and it has the same effect `[ngModel]="selectedGroupingFields[i]"`

**ANSWERED**

This is now working and used for an Open Source library of mine [Angular-Slickgrid](https://github.com/ghiscoding/Angular-Slickgrid) and here's the [demo](https://ghiscoding.github.io/Angular-Slickgrid/#/draggrouping) of where I use this answer. Thanks :)

Comment: You are using one ngModels in 3 select boxes, So it should behve like that only

Comment: @SoumyaGangamwar hmm ok I see but is there a way to fix it to get it working with the `ngFor`? I would be happy to see an answer that I could use and accept. Thanks

Comment: Do `[(ngModel)]="groupField"` instead of `[(ngModel)]="selectedGroupingFields[i]"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this problem by providing a `trackBy` function to the `ngFor` directive:

```
<div ... *ngFor="let groupField of selectedGroupingFields; let i = index; trackBy: trackByFn">
  <select ... name="groupField{{i}}" [(ngModel)]="selectedGroupingFields[i]" (ngModelChange)="groupByFieldName($event, i)">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option [ngValue]="field.id" *ngFor="let field of columnDefinitions">{{field.name}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

where `trackByFn` returns the item `index`:

```
trackByFn(index, item) {
  return index;
}
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6yezhx) for a demo.

Comment: ahh yes this is working, great. I don't use the TrackBy very often but is there a way to put that code all in the view (without creating ViewModel code)?

Comment: I don't think so. You cannot create a function in the HTML template.

Comment: Yeah it doesn't look like, I tried it and that didn't work. Thanks a lot for the working solution, this is for an Open Source lib [Angular-Slickgrid](https://github.com/ghiscoding/Angular-Slickgrid) and here's the [demo](https://ghiscoding.github.io/Angular-Slickgrid/#/draggrouping)... so you helped me helped others :)  Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Hey you are using two way data binding

```
[(ngModel)]=selectedGroupingFields[i]
```

To make it work as you wish you can make it as following:

```
<div class="col-sm-3" *ngFor="let groupField of selectedGroupingFields; let i = index;">
 <select class="form-control col-sm-6" name="groupField{{i}}" [ngModel]="selectedGroupingFields[i]" (ngModelChange)="groupByFieldName($event, i)">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option [ngValue]="field.id" *ngFor="let field of columnDefinitions">{{field.name}} 
 </option>
</select>
```

Please check working example here: [Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-oxkhen?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: Oh I forgot to mention that I tried with `[ngModel]` only and that still behave the same. I tried your code and I still see the problem :(

Comment: I edited my answer and added working example on stackblitz. Please check if that's working for you.

Comment: it's unfortunate that even after copying your code it still didn't work, however @ConnorsFan answer does work. However your blitz code does work, so I'll up vote anyway. Thanks

Comment: When I tried the stackblitz, I had some strange behavior when clicking on the button. For example: (1) Select a value in the first list, (2) Click on the button, (3) See that the value of the second list changed.