# In ngFor select option how to send the value of particular object property at onChange

Tags: angular

```
<select class="form-control" (change)="onChange(user.id)">
            <option disabled selected="selected">By User</option>
          <option *ngFor="let user of allUsers">{{user.first_name}} {{user.first_name}}</option>
        </select>
```

The first name and last name is only for displaying what value i need to send to the ts file is `user.id`

`(change)="onChange(user.id)` does work because it is outside of the loop. I need to send the value of selected user id on very change.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33716321/1273882

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the `user.id` to the value of the `<option>` tag:

```
<select class="form-control" (change)="onChange($event.target.value)">
  <option disabled selected="selected">Invoice By User</option>
  <option *ngFor="let user of allUsers" [value]="user.id">
    {{user.first_name}} {{user.first_name}}
  </option>
</select>
```

See [here](https://angular.io/guide/forms#add-powers-with-ngfor) for more examples and information

Answer (score 0):

```
<select class="form-control" formControlName="userInvoice" (change)="onChange()">
  <option disabled selected="selected">Invoice By User</option>
  <option *ngFor="let user of allUsers" [value]="user.id">
    {{user.first_name}} {{user.first_name}}
  </option>
</select>

onChange(){
    console.log(this.userInvoiceformGroup.get('userInvoice').value);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try below:

```
<select (change)="onChange($event.target.value)">
    <option *ngFor="let user of allUsers">{{user.first_name}} {{user.first_name}}</option>
</select>
```

And `onChange` like this

```
onChange(user) {
    console.log(user);
}
```