# ngModelChange dispatchEvent

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine

I'm trying to test a select element...

```
  <select [ngModel]="selectedRouters" name="routerName" class="form-control" id="routersSelect" size="12" (ngModelChange)="selectRouters($event)" multiple>
    <option [value]="router.name" *ngFor="let router of routers$ | orderBy : 'name'">
      {{router.name}}
    </option>
  </select>
```

with the method looking like:

```
selectRouters(routers) {
    this.routers$
        .filter(router => routers.includes(router.name))
        .forEach(router => router.setSelected(true))

    this.routers$
        .filter(router => !routers.includes(router.name))
        .forEach(router => router.setSelected(false))
}
```

The method is expecting `string[]` but I don't know how to test this...

```
//before
component = fixture.componentInstance

//it
component.selectedRouters = Array.of(r.name);

let evt = document.createEvent('Event');
evt.initEvent('ngModelChange');

selector.dispatchEvent(evt);

// also tried

selector.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('ngModelChange') {
  detail: ["arg1"]
})
```

But the argument is called with an event type not `string[]` which is throwing errors in the code.

Does anyone know how to do this, or how I can test a select element being selected?

Answer (score 1):

You can check by changing in HTML  `[(ngModel)]="selectedRouters` and `(ngModelChange)="selectRouters(selectedRouters)"` as follows

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedRouters" name="routerName" class="form-control" id="routersSelect" size="12" (ngModelChange)="selectRouters(selectedRouters)" multiple>
    <option [value]="router.name" *ngFor="let router of routers$ | orderBy : 'name'">
      {{router.name}}
    </option>
  </select>
```

***Or*** you can do like same as you did inside HTML Page and just change the component code as follow

**In HTML page**

```
  <select [ngModel]="selectedRouters" name="routerName" class="form-control" id="routersSelect" size="12" (ngModelChange)="selectRouters($event)" multiple>
    <option [value]="router.name" *ngFor="let router of routers$ | orderBy : 'name'">
      {{router.name}}
    </option>
  </select>
```

**In Component page**

```
    selectRouters(event) {
    this.routers$
        .filter(router => routers.includes(event.target.value.toString()))
        .forEach(router => router.setSelected(true))

    this.routers$
        .filter(router => !routers.includes(event.target.value.toString()))
        .forEach(router => router.setSelected(false))
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33700266/how-can-i-get-new-selection-in-select-in-angular-2?answertab=active#tab-top) code to resolve your concern. Hope this helps! Thank you.