# Why change event not fired when select already selected option?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am using angular reactive forms, the change method for select field is not fired when I select already selected option.
Here is the link
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2e1cvz
in this example if I select option 1, event fired but if I select again 1 event is not fired.

Comment: You cannot use `ngModel` with reactive forms.

Comment: any other event that could I used.

Comment: you can use change event if there is no two way binding `(change)="onChange($event.target.value)"`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get new selection in "select" in Angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33700266/how-can-i-get-new-selection-in-select-in-angular-2)

Comment: actually I want to trigger change event on select for already selected option.
in short on every option's click event should be triggered, even for already selected option.

Answer (score 0):

As the name of the event says it will only trigger when it detects a change in value, if u select the same value again means that is not change in value thats why select field hadn't triggered change event.

Comment: any other method that you know to capture select value, on option click.