# In Angular how do I define a "router" member field?

Tags: angular, callback, routes, router, angular9

For Angular 9, I have a parent component in which I want to pass a function to a child component.  I want to pass the "onNavigate" function to the child component ...

```
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
...
export class StatsComponent implements OnInit {
    
  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private apiService: ApiService
  ) { }

    ...

  onNavigate(event): void {
    const id = event.target.value;
    if(parseInt(id) !== this.itemId) {
      const url = `/stats/${this.itemId}`;
      this.router.navigateByUrl(url);
    }
  }
```

The parent component looks like this ...

```
<form id="statForm" method="get">
    <app-item-menu [default_selected]="itemId"
                        [value_change_callback]="onNavigate"></app-item-menu>
</form>
```

The child component looks pretty simple ...

```
<select id="item" (change)="valueChangeCallback($event)">
    <option *ngFor="let item of items"
        [selected]="item.id === default_selected">{{item.path}}</option>
</select>
```

But when I change an item in the menu, I get a

```
ERROR TypeError: this.router is undefined
```

in the "onNavigate" method.  How else do I need to be defining my router?

Comment: Yeah this is problematic.. probably not a good idea to pass functions around this way. You are loosing the ‘this’ scope.. and I can’t really see a way in your setup to re-bind this to the correct scope. Better to rethink this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should really read the angular guide at angular.io, but just to get you going as close to your implementation as possible.

The parent component:

```html
<form id="statForm" method="get">
    <app-item-menu [default_selected]="itemId"
                        (valueChangeCallback)="onNavigate($event)"></app-item-menu>
</form>
```

The child component:

```html
<select id="item" (change)="valueChangeCallback.emit($event)">
    <option *ngFor="let item of items"
        [selected]="item.id === default_selected">{{item.path}}</option>
</select>
```

And make your `valueChangeCallback` an output property, instead of an input:

```
//...
Output()
valueChangeCallback: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to mark a property on the child component with the @Output() decorator, this allows you to send data from child to parent or just react to that event in any way.
Add the property to you app-item-menu component

```
@Output() idChanged = new EventEmitter<string>();
```

then the child component (app-item-menu) needs to emit this event, you can do this in your change method for example.

```
public changeId($event: any): void {
  this.idChanged.next($event.id); // no idea where the id is, but I hope you get it.
}
HTML:
<select id="item" (change)="changeId($event)">
    <option *ngFor="let item of items"
        [selected]="item.id === default_selected">{{item.path}}</option>
</select>
```

In the parent component you can bind a method to the above event.

```
<form id="statForm" method="get">
    <app-item-menu [default_selected]="itemId"
                        (idChanged)="onNavigate($event)"></app-item-menu>
</form>
```

If you need more information, [read the docs](https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs#sending-data-to-a-parent-component)

Comment: Thanks.  I implemented everything as you have it, but the changeId function is never called when I select a different option from the dropdown.  Is "(ngModelChange)" the right way to set that output on the child component?

Comment: There [are different ways to do it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33716321/5171325).
You can change it back to `<select (change)="changeId($event)">` if you want.