# How to fire a click event to make a selection from a dropdown list in Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, dropdown, mouseclick-event

I have a list-group got from ngFor as below. By clicking on any of a listed items, I can fire a click event and made the selection happening as I expected.

```html
<div>
    <ul class="list-group my-3">
        <li class="list-group-item" 
        *ngFor="let category of categories"
        [class.active]="category.id === this.shopParams.categoryId"
        [value]="category.id"
        (click)="onCategorySelected(category.id)"
        >
        {{category.name}}
        </li>                
    </ul>
</div>
```

However, once I changed the list-group into a dropdown list, the click event seems never fired although an item can be selected by clicking it from the dropdown list.

```html
<div>                    
      <select name="cars" class="custom-select mb-3">
          <option *ngFor="let category of categories" 
              [class.active]="category.id === this.shopParams.categoryId"
              [value]="category.id"
              (click)="onCategorySelected(category.id)"
              >
              {{category.name}}                       
          </option>                    
      </select>
 </div>
```

Here is my click function in component.ts

```js
onCategorySelected(categoryId: number) {
    const params = this.shopService.getShopParams();
    params.categoryId = categoryId;
    this.shopService.setShopParams(params);
}
```

Can any one point out what the problem is and help me out with correction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can do to get the selected value:

```
<div>
    <select name="cars" class="custom-select mb-3" (change)="onCategorySelected($event.target.value)">
          <option *ngFor="let category of categories" 
              [value]="category.id"
              >
              {{category.name}}                       
          </option>                    
      </select>
</div>
```

Note the `change` event on the `select`. I pass the `$event.target.value` in the `onCategorySelected()` method to get the selected id.

For some reason, the `click` event does not works directly on the `option` tag, at least with the default select tag from html.

Also [here is a link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33716321/9868549) if you need more possible solution to get values from a `select`.

Comment: Thank you so much Quentin! Your great answer works!