# event.target.value as a number?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

```
const [data, Setdata] = useState<number[] >([]);
const [inputData, SetinputData] = useState<number>(0);
const [canAdd, SetcanAdd] = useState<boolean>(true);

  const numberField = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    SetcanAdd(false)
    SetinputData(event.target.value);


    if(data.includes(event.target.value)){
      SetcanAdd(true)
    }

    // event.target.value Argument of type string is not assignable to parameter of type number
  };

  //jsx
    <input
        onChange={numberField }
        placeholder="add numbers"
        type="number"
        value={inputData}
     />
```

How can I set the `event.target.value` to be a number?

I know I can set everything to string, but I want it to be a number

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Changed event.target.value to event.target.valueAsNumber.

Works now!

Edit: Lol, the answer was in my title

Answer (score 4):

In JS, it won't be a number, even if the input is of `type="number"`:

```js
const val = document.querySelector('input').value;
console.log(typeof val);
console.log(val);
```

```html
<input type="number" value=80>
```

So you shouldn't try to have `event.target.value` be typed as a number, because *it isn't*.

You'll have to convert it to a number yourself explicitly, if that's what you want.

```
const numValue = Number(event.target.value);
// use numValue
```

Comment: This. Plus you can use `parseInt` or `parseFloat` to convert it.

Answer (score 3):

you can try:

1. event.target.valueAsNumber
2. +event.target.value
3. Number(event.target.value)
4. parseInt(event.target.value) || parseFloat(event.target.value)