# How to trigger (change) event in Angular 2+

Tags: angular, typescript

In my component.html, I have this select tag:

```
  <select class="inputGlobalStyle" [(ngModel)]="_user.profession" id="profession"
   [ngClass]="{'redInput': _user.professionError != null }" (change)="onSelectProfession($event)">
    <option [value]="undefined" *ngIf="_user.profession === undefined" selected>Choose a profession</option>
    <option *ngFor="let profession of professionsList" value="{{profession.activityCode}}">
      {{profession.activityWording}}
    </option>
  </select>
```

And there is the function in my component.ts

```
  onSelectProfession(event: Event) {
    let professionCode = event.target['options'][event.target['options'].selectedIndex].value;
    let activityWording = event.target['options'][event.target['options'].selectedIndex].text;
    console.log(professionCode);
    console.log(activityWording);

    this.subscriptionService.activityWording = activityWording;
  }
```

Is there a way to trigger the method "onSelectProfession($event)" to be able to fill the professionCode & activityWording variables automatically in update user case??

Thanks.

Comment: This answer helps you? 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33700266/how-can-i-get-new-selection-in-select-in-angular-2

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply, it doesn't help me to do what expected, but contains a lot of useful informations. thanks

Comment: You’re welcome. I'm happy to read it!