# Why is the event target the select element rather than the option selected?

Tags: javascript, angular

Using angular 11 and trying to get the value of the option element when I select an option. I've looked at probably 20 docs / so answers that say to do this:

html:

```
    <select class="ui-select ui-select--large" (change)="fn($event)">
      <option [value]="null" selected disabled>Select somthing</option>
      <ng-container *ngIf="values">
         <option *ngFor="let value of values [value]="value.id">{{ value.name }}</option>
      </ng-container>
    </select>
```

ts:

```
  fn(event) {
    console.log(event.target);
  }
```

When I select an option the select element itself gets logged, not the option element that I selected. Why?

Comment: Because it's the `select` element that `change`d...

Comment: The change event it's on select so it's normal the target is it self

Comment: try `event.target.value` to get the selected value?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol then why does this answer which was accepted with 800+ upvotes say to do this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33700266/how-can-i-get-new-selection-in-select-in-angular-2 (many other answers also say this) Anyway if this is wrong, then how can I access the option value?

Comment: This isn't like the click event. As mentioned in the comments, it is the `select` element that is the target of the change event. The options aren't changing

Comment: @JonP please see my comment above

Comment: @HelloWorld, you are miss reading `$event.target.value` if that is what you are referring to in the link. That is the value of the select box, determined by the selected option. Form elements have a value attribute/property

Comment: @JonP - looking at the event object you are definitely right! If you'd like please make this an answer so I can accept and others can learn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, the `select` element is the target of the change event. The options don't change. This is a little different from the click event.

The `select` element has a value attribute/property you can access with `event.target.value`

Answer (score 1):

you can use a more closer Angular way, see [the docs](https://angular.io/guide/two-way-binding#adding-two-way-data-binding)

Usign a variable and ngModel two binding

```
//define a variable in ts
value:any
<select class="ui-select ui-select--large" [(ngModel)]="value">
   ...
</select>
{{value}} <--to check the variable
```

You always has in the variable "value" the value

Using two binding "split" the bannana notation to add a function:

```
//define a variable in ts
value:any
<select class="ui-select ui-select--large" [ngModel]="value"
   (ngModelChange)="value=$event;fn($event)">
   ...
</select>
{{value}} <--to check the variable
```

Using a [template reference variable](https://angular.io/guide/template-reference-variables#syntax)

```
//define a variable in ts
value:any
<select #myselect class="ui-select ui-select--large" 
   [value]="value"
   (change)="fn(myselect.value)">
   ...
</select>
```

See that, in this case "value" not is actualized -only it's used to give an initial value

Answer (score 0):

The onclick event.target.value should return SELECT while opening a select Dropdown by mouse click and OPTION when click on an option. This is the correct behavior like Firefox do. Chrome gives back "SELECT" in both cases.

In chrome it is impossible (or i found no way until now) to reset a list to the first option while opening the Dropdown. In both cases a a SELECT is fired and the list will always stay on first option.

```js
let myelement = document.getElementById("myid");
myelement.setAttribute("onclick","revertBack(this, event)");
myelement.setAttribute("onchange","mylementSelect(myelement)");

function revertBack(myelement, event){
console.log(myelement.nodeName + "-" + event.target.tagName);
    if (event.target.tagName == "SELECT") { 
            myelement.selectedIndex = 0;
      myelement.style.color = 'gray';
        myelement.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
    }
}
    
function mylementSelect(myelement){
  if (myelement.selectedIndex <= 0) {
     myelement.style.color = 'gray';
       myelement.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
  } else {
      myelement.style.color ='black';
        myelement.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
    }
}
```

```html
<!-- 
try this in Chrome and Firefox and compare Log Result 
On firefox a selected option will be reset to the first option on chrome not
-->
    
<select id="myid">
<option value="1">Option 1</option>
<option value="2">Option 2</option>
<option value="3">Option 3</option>
<option value="4">Option 4</option>
<option value="5">Option 5</option>
<option value="6">Option 6</option>
<option value="7">Option 7</option>
</select>
```