# cascading dropdown in angular using typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, data-binding, cascadingdropdown

I am getting the response from three diff APIs in angular.
all the APIs are called in ngOnInit since we have dependency on each other.
How to make cascading dropdown like if i selected the 'India' from first drop down then all the city of india should come in second dropdown and when i select delhi from second dropdown then all the values of delhi should come in third dropdown

API 1 response

```
{id: 0, name: "India"}
{id: 1, name: "US"}
```

API 2 response

```
{id: 0, name: "India", city: "delhi"}
{id: 1, name: "US", city: "NYK"}
{id: 2, name: "India", city: "chennai"}
{id: 3, name: "US", city: "WDC"}
{id: 4, name: "India", city: "mumbai"}
{id: 5, name: "India", city: "NewJs"}
```

API 3 response

```
{id: 0, name: "block1", dist: "delhi"}
{id: 1, name: "block2", dist: "NYK"}
{id: 2, name: "block3", dist: "Chennai"}
{id: 3, name: "block4", dist: "delhi"}
{id: 4, name: "block5", dist: "WDC"}
{id: 5, name: "block6", dist: "NewJs"}
{id: 6, name: "block7", dist: "mumbai"}
{id: 7, name: "block8", dist: "delhi"}
{id: 8, name: "block9", dist: "NYK"}
```

component.ts

```
export class CreateInfraRequestComponent implements OnInit {
 Country:any;
 City:any;
 Block:any;
 selectedCountry:any;
 selectedCity:any;
 selectedBlock:any;
 constructor(private infraService : InfraRequestService){  };
 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getAllCountry();
    this.getAllCity();
    this.getAllblock();
}
getAllCountry (){
  this.infraService.getAllInfraRequest("apiUrlForCountyr").subscribe((data)=>{
  this.Country=data;
    console.log(data);
  });
}

getAllCity(){
    this.infraService.getAllInfraRequest("apiUrlForCity").subscribe((data)=>{
    this.City=data;
     console.log(data);
    });    
}
getAllblock(){
  this.infraService.getAllInfraRequest("apiUrlForBlock").subscribe((data)=>{
  this.Block=data;
    console.log(data);
  });    
}

}
```

component.html

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedCountry">                   
        <option *ngFor="let country of Country" [value]="country.name">
          {{country.name}}
        </option>            
    </select>
  <select [(ngModel)]="selectedCity">                   
        <option *ngFor="let city of City" [value]="city.name">
          {{city.name}}
        </option>            
    </select>
  <select [(ngModel)]="selectedBlock">                   
        <option *ngFor="let block of Block" [value]="block.name">
          {{block.name}}
        </option>            
    </select>
```

Comment: You're using selectedCountry, selectedCity, selectedBlock in component.html and they have no instances in component.ts. Please edit your code accordingly

Comment: @KartikDolas thanks for pointing, code edited. could please explain know how can i achieve above problem statement ?

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve your problem will be to listen to changes with a change event. What you want to do is

- Trigger a change event each time a selection change happens with:

  <select [ngModel]="selectedCountry" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)" name="sel2">

  {country.name}}
- Then in ts file get access to value with - and assign it to the next select item

  ```
  onChange(newValue) {
  console.log(newValue);
  this.City = newValue;
  }
  ```

This post can help you further:
[How can I get new selection in "select" in Angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33700266/how-can-i-get-new-selection-in-select-in-angular-2)

Comment: i'm able to get the selected value from first dropdown, but the problem is how to filter the data of second dropdown based on first dropdown selection

Comment: let's say that user selected a country option. In city select, you bind value to select options using City array right? Then loop over it with *ngFor="let city of City". In OnChange() function triggered from country, you can filter the City array with const filteredResult = this.City.filter(city=> city.value == value); and assign  the result to the City array.