# When I'm scraping Angular app nothing happens when I change select options

Tags: javascript, angular, web-scraping, scrapy, screen-scraping

[image]

When I'm trying to change options in select "event doesn't load like ((ngModelChange) or (ngchnage))"

[image]

I tried this for change selected option, but no event loaded
`document.querySelectorAll("select")[1].value=2"` and
`document.querySelectorAll("select option")[2].selected=true;`

Comment: Without more code its hard to say precise but it could be that the value should be changed using [ngModel]="SOME_VAR" if you add more code to the question i would be happy to investigate more

Comment: Checkout this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33700266/how-can-i-get-new-selection-in-select-in-angular-2